# I must process the sentence by calling the method rather than processing the string directly in my main method! PS i need to use void method

Tags: java, methods, void

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrintVertical
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a sentence: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();

        int i =0;
        System.out.println("Your sentence printed vertically is:");
        for(i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char letter = input.charAt(i);
 
            System.out.println(letter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put the question inside the heading, write it in your question and put in the headline just a concise question which is representing it in a few words.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Comment: Try `Stream.of(input.toCharArray()).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Thank you so much for responding and I'm sorry about my mistakes also I'm kind of new to this. I'm really sorry and thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

- Write a new method besides the main-method in your class and mark it with the keyword **static**.(Class Methods)
- Give it a String as Parameter. To call it with your user input.

**The Static Function:**

```
  public static void doVertic(String inp){   
    int i =0;
    System.out.println("Your sentence printed vertically is:");
    for(i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char letter = input.charAt(i);

        System.out.println(letter);
    }
}
```

- Then call it with your scanned input inside the **main** method

**Call in Main Method:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a sentence: ");
    String input = in.nextLine();
    <Classname>.doVertic(input);
}
```

Note: The <Classname> have to be your **Classname**